# docker-compose - what is for build, and what is for runtime?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

I am migrating an application from running in Docker (using `docker-compose up`) to Kubernetes.  We are still using `docker-compose.yml` for building the images.

I'm aware several of the config settings for the services are for build, and some are for runtime (`docker-compose up`). So, I'd like to remove those settings that won't be used in the Kubernetes environment.

I *think* I'm finding the right ones to remove, but I couldn't seem to find a definitive list, or whether each setting is for build or runtime (e.g. the docker-compose documentation for `environment` just says "Add environment variables".

This is my list of runtime (`docker-compose up`) settings that I think would be safe to remove if I'm just building with docker-compose.

Validation of this list would be helpful, or a pointer to some documentation somewhere.

- `container_name`
- `restart`
- `init`
- `depends_on`
- `environment`
- `ports`
- `expose`  (can put in Dockerfile?)
- `command`
- `environment`
- `volumes`

So, actually, all I would need is `image` and `build` for each service? Would that be right? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* of those settings are run-time settings.  The only build-time settings are the things in the `build:` block and the `image:` name.

That having been said, a couple of these things can be specified in the Dockerfile.  The Dockerfile `EXPOSE`, `CMD`, and `ENV` directives provide defaults for the corresponding Compose settings.  If you have a useful default command, or an environment-variable setting that will *always* be the same no matter where you run the container (for example, path-related variables), set them in the Dockerfile.

`expose:` in a Compose file does pretty much nothing at all and it's always safe to remove it.  You should not usually need to override `container_name:`.  Most Compose applications do not need more than the `default` network and you can usually delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the `docker-compose.yml` file; Kubernetes does not support multiple segregated networks in any case.

`restart:`, `environment:`, and `command:` have Kubernetes equivalents; see the [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/) API reference.  Unlike Compose containers, Pods default to `restartPolicy: Always`.  Note that Kubernetes `command:` overrides the image's `ENTRYPOINT` and Kubernetes `args:` the `CMD`; the terminology is slightly different from Docker.  You can reasonably need `environment:` settings to point at things like database hostnames that will be different in Kubernetes.

`depends_on:` does not exist in any form in Kubernetes.  In Compose its most important effect is to ensure that some other host name exists; in Kubernetes you get this effect by creating a related Service.  In much the same way as [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) you will need to manually ensure the dependency is available in Kubernetes, or tolerate it being unavailable.

`init:` does not exist in Kubernetes either.  If you need an init process to be process 1 in your container, install something like [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) in your image.

`volumes:` is the most complicated one here.  I've seen several uses for this:

- If `volumes:` injects a configuration file from the host system, put it in a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) and mount that in your Deployment spec.
- If `volumes:` hold log files, consider reconfiguring your application to log to stdout instead.  If you can't do this, you'll need to work with a DevOps engineer to figure out how to extract logs from your containers.
- If `volumes:` hold persistent data like database data, run your container as a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/); each replica will get its own PersistentVolumeClaim with cluster-managed storage.
- If `volumes:` inject your application code or libraries, delete them; the code should be packaged in the image.

There are tools like [Kompose](https://kompose.io/) that can attempt to convert a `docker-compose.yml` file into Kubernetes manifests, but there are a lot of corner cases (like ConfigMaps for example) and I'd suggest using these as a starting point rather than assuming it will convert successfully.

Comment: That is an awesome answer! Thank you David!  I had started using tini, and, yes, I'm just working my through rearranging volumes into configMaps and secrets